# React Useeffect returning null array in first

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

I making a react project and while data loading i need take my datas from json with fetch-get. But while i doing it its sending empty array in first then 1-2second later sending me datas. So while its empty data my render is starting so my application is crashing. How can i make it without get empty data ?  My codes :

```
const { id } = useParams();
  const [articles, setArticles] = useState([]);
  const [collection, setCollection] = useState([]);

 

     useEffect(() => {
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/article/bycollection/" + `${id}`)
          .then((x) => x.json())
          .then((z) => {
            setArticles(z);
          }, []);
        fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/collection/" + `${id}`)
          .then((x) => x.json())
          .then((z) => {
            setCollection(z);
          }, []);
      }, [id]);
```

Empty error line :

```
return ( 
      <div className="tomiddle ">
          <div className="mb-3">
            <BreadCrumbComp data={breadCrumbData} />
          </div>
    
          <div className="collectionBg">
            <div className="collectionHeader flex">
              <div className="w-32 h-32 p-4 mt-2 text-5xl">
                <i className={collection.icon}></i>
              </div>
              <div>
                <h1 className="collectionTitle ">{collection.name}</h1>
                <WriterGroupInfo groupData={collection} /> // Here i getting error. 
                      Its sending empty collection
              </div>
            </div>)
```

WriterGroupInfo :

```
const WriterGroupInfo = (props) => {
  const prop = props.groupData;
  console.log("prop=>", props); // Showing empty array.
  const articles = prop.articles.slice(0, 3);
  const last = articles[articles.length - 1];
  const lastAuthor = articles.length > 1 ? " ve " + last.author.name : "";

  const authorNames =
    articles
      .slice(0, 2)
      .map((a) => a.author.name)
      .join(", ") + lastAuthor;

  return (
    
    <div className="flex  pt-4  ">
      <Avatar.Group>
        {articles.map((x) => (
          <Avatar key={x.id} src={x.author.avatar} />
        ))}
      </Avatar.Group>
      <div className="text-collection-small-500 truncate text-xs pl-2 pt-1">
        <span>Bu koleksiyonda {prop.articles.length} makale mevcut</span>
        <br />

        {articles.length > 0 ? (
          <span className="truncate mr-2">
            <span className="text-gray-400 ">Yazarlar: </span>
            {authorNames}
          </span>
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Why are you passing an empty array to `.then`? What error are you getting? What does the `WriterGroupInfo` component look like? etc. etc. Please provide more data, we can't help you with no more than you've posted.

Comment: @JaredSmith Where do i passing empty array ? My data's is not empty in normally. Wait bro i will edit my question for writergroupinfo sorry.

Comment: @JaredSmith I edit. Can you check again please ?

Comment: You're passing an empty array in your fetch response handling, which is incorrect usage of the Promise API.

Comment: @JaredSmith I actually dont understand where do i passing empty data. While i check like 
` .then((z) => { 
console.log(z) 
           // setArticles(z);
          }, []);` like that i can see my data.

Comment: The edit you made (as well as the original question) is riddled with typos. Clean up basic coding things *before* posting a question. I can't even follow what you're *trying* to do because of all of the mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because you are setting the first value of collecion as an empty array:

```
const [collection, setCollection] = useState([]);
```

You should handle this situations like this:

```
return ( 
  <div className="tomiddle ">
      <div className="mb-3">
        <BreadCrumbComp data={breadCrumbData} />
      </div>
     {collection.length === 0 ?
      <div> No data for collection </div> :
      <div className="collectionBg">
        <div className="collectionHeader flex">
          <div className="w-32 h-32 p-4 mt-2 text-5xl">
            <i className={collection.icon}></i>
          </div>
          <div>
            <h1 className="collectionTitle ">{collection.name}</h1>
            <WriterGroupInfo groupData={collection} /> // Here i getting error. 
                  Its sending empty collection
          </div>
        }
        </div>)
```

Comment: I'm sorry. Im kinda newbie in React. I did like that but its asking 1 more parameter for else return. So i gave null to it. and when my page load i cant see anything coz its sending null.  (While loading page sending empty array so its not waiting for filled data.So its making null)

Comment: dont worry, try copy all the code that I wrote, if the problem is that your are receiving null from the endpoint you should check what are you receiving inside the `then` of your request with `console.log`s

Answer (score 0):

Your callback inside useEffect has 2 async calls and you are not waiting for them to finish. They take their time. Before that the next render has **already** taken place and for that reason you have your data empty for some time until your fetch(and subsequent `setState`) is completed.
Since both fetch are independent you can wait for them using `Promise.all` and `await`.

```
useEffect( () => { 
async yourFunction() {
let promise1 = fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/article/bycollection/" + `${id}`).then((x) => x.json()).then((z) => {
            setArticles(z);
          });
let promise2 = fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/collection/" + `${id}`).then((x) => x.json())
          .then((z) => {
            setCollection(z);
          });

let results = await Promise.all([promise1,promise2]);
}
yourFunction();

}, [id]);
```

Also, `[]` as an extra parameter for the second `then()` is not required in my opinion.

Comment: thanks for reply but its still same brother. Its still seeing first empty array.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is UseEffect works asynchronously and it triggers after the initial render. So at the initial render, it tries to populate using null/Empty array values. You can initiate the passing array values using useState like const[value,setValue]=useState([]) .

Comment: I'm sorry if i get wrong but, i already used useState and its giving error brother.

Comment: ye bro you just declare the whole collection as empty. colletion=[] and try to access inner elements inside the declared collections like collection.article. You pass a empty array to the child element. and try to access a element which is not inside the empty element. If you initialize some thing like `useState([article=[ firstname = ""] ]) ` you want get errors. best thing is to use different states for article name and author then pass theme separately to child component. you can populate them inside when useEffect populate the data